# WP7 Shoutcast with MediaStreamSource

Tags: windows-phone-7, shoutcast, mediastreamsource

I am trying to implement the Shoutcast streaming to my MediaElement via MediaStreamSource. Here is a code with some basics. With the ReadData method I can download raw audio data (MP3 samples), my question is how can I set the stream to the MediaStreamSource. In this way it doesn't work (it compiles and there are no errors on MediaFailed event but i can't hear any sound). Maybe should I implement all of these in my custom ShoutcastMediaStreamSource? There is no problem with fixed stream, just with non-fixed. Can somebody give me some advice?

On the WP7 there is no possibility to set the "useUnsafeHeaderParsing" so I can't get http headers with shoutcast metadata - only raw data.
In the ShoutcastMediaStreamSource i have implemented some code of ManagedMediaHelpers.

Thanks

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://radiozetmp3-02.eurozet.pl:8400/;"); 
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers["Icy-MetaData"] = "1";
        request.UserAgent = "WinampMPEG/5.09";
        request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RequestComplete), request);
        allDone.WaitOne();

        ShoutcastMediaStreamSource smss = new ShoutcastMediaStreamSource(stream);
        player.SetSource(smss); // MediaElement
        player.Play();
    }

    public void RequestComplete(IAsyncResult r)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(r) as HttpWebResponse;
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        IAsyncResult res = stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callback, null);

        allDone.Set();
    }

    public void ReadData(IAsyncResult r)
    {
        int bytes = stream.EndRead(r);

        if (bytes == 0) { Debug.WriteLine("No bytes readed"); }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("readed: " + buffer.Length.ToString());
            stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callback, buffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you figured this out, I'm trying to get the samething done. Any leads ?

Comment: Just for kicks, don't pass an ICY header, just use regular HTTP, and load it with a semicolon in the URL, like this:  `http://10.12.13.14:8000/;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to develop custom MediaStreamSource.

You can find the prototype of one that I developed for one of my projects here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=eb0868f2135b874c&resid=EB0868F2135B874C!1037&parid=EB0868F2135B874C!169&authkey=!AGSYfCVvCasGArI

Comment: I'm getting some skip sound in every 5 sec or so. Please advise how we can avoid that?

Comment: It works only for 128 bit rate streams. Other wise it returns  "chimpanzee voices"

Answer (score 0):

Try version =2 in the code. It works for me now after changing one line of code