# SHOUTcast in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, streaming, shoutcast

I know people have asked this before, but i see no answer nor people even commenting about it.

So, i'm  trying to make SHOUTcast streaming in WP7, anyone have done it? I know i have to use MediaStreamSource with my MediaElement, but how exactly can i skip that header from SHOUTcast and just get the stream and use it in a MediaStreamSource? Is there any app that has done it? Someone actually has some example working code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 Shoutcast with MediaStreamSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319882/wp7-shoutcast-with-mediastreamsource)

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good SHOUTcast Player called streamything (http://www.streamything.com/page/en/default.html) . Unfortunately it is not open source nor freeware but i shows that it is definitely a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a mechanism to get the stream of data to be passed to the application continuously. [Here](http://dennisdel.com/?p=528) is a possible implementation. In order to be able to receive the stream directly (so that the application won't be treated as a web browser), you have to call the URL with a semicolon at the end. For example: `http://00.00.00.00:8000/;`